# Ruby / concerns / inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-attributes, activesupport-concern

Using Ruby 3.1.1.

Trying to implement similar to: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb :: class_attribute :fields

When I include a model concern on a parent model the class_attributes seem to get merged on child models. I wanted to maintain a seperate class_attribute hash on each child class, like the mongoid Field concern does.

This only seems to occur when inheriting.

```
module Dashboardable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :dashboard_fields

    self.dashboard_fields = {}
  end

  class_methods do
    def dashboard_field(name, options = {})
      dashboard_fields[name] = options.merge(klass: self)
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Dashboardable

  dashboard_field :first_name
end

class Foo < Person
  dashboard_field :foot
  field :foot, type: String
end

class Bar < Person
  dashboard_field :bart
  field :bart, type: String
end

Foo.dashboard_fields: [:first_name, :foot]

Bar.dashboard_fields: [:first_name, :foot, :bart]

Foo.fields: ["_id", "_type", "foot"]

Bar.fields: ["_id", "_type", "bart"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a lot of edits and some digging to figure out the question and whats going on. Sorry.

Whats happening is that with `class_attribute` is that all the classes are actually sharing the same object in thier instance attributes. This is [an intended behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34868).

You can actually get it to work with `class_attribute` if you make sure that each subclass gets a duplicate of the "parent hash":

```ruby
module Dashboardable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :dashboard_fields, default: {}
  end

  class_methods do
    def inherited(subclass)
      subclass.class_eval { self.dashboard_fields = superclass.dashboard_fields.dup } 
    end

    def dashboard_field(name, options = {})
      dashboard_fields[name] = options.merge(klass: self)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Max for the useful answer. However, I would like to inherit from the parent, but the child classes seem to effect each other. In my example, the parent class adds first_name which I would like inheriting. Why does Bar.dashboard_fields: [:first_name, :foot, :bart]
have foot in? that is set in a sibling class. Apologies if I have misunderstood your answer

Comment: I added an edit on how you can make it inherit. I think you may actually have uncovered a bug in `class_attribute` - I tried it out and the subclasses are actually sharing the same object reference with each other but not the parent class.

Comment: ah ok I think I understand now - reset and inherit. Many thanks Max! this has been annoying me all weekend, I was sure it was something I was doing wrong. Thing is I followed the fields attribute in https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb and sibling classes do not conflict fields.

Comment: I checked my obj_ids and got different ones:

Person.object_id: 20940

Bar.object_id: 20960
Foo.object_id: 20980
Bar.dashboard_fields: [:first_name, :bart, :foot]
Foo.dashboard_fields: [:first_name, :bart, :foot]
Bar.fields: ["_id", "_type", "bart"]
Foo.fields: ["_id", "_type", "foot"]

Comment: And do you see how mongoid fields keys are not polluting across siblings? And I am trying to use exactly the same strategy

Comment: Just tried your way with the added inheritance and works perfectly! Max points to @max!!

Comment: I think I also figured out what is going on. With `class_attributes` your classes each have their own class instance variable but they all seem to be sharing the same hash object. I'm not sure if this is the actual intended behavior or a bug. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/2d70b9a8ed088bd731404ec26d74851b

Comment: Ah, its actually an intended behavior. Yikes. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34868

Comment: ah so the class_att is shared by reference, so a child altering it will effect the parent and all other children? Makes sense, although somehow mongoid fields avoids this - https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb